# TypeError when concatenating two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

**Background -**
I have two pandas DataFrames, as follows -
**restaurant_df**

[image]

And **zipcodes_df:**
[image]

**Issue -**
Both DataFrames have the same row count of 130, however I am having issues when trying to merge these together.

**My code -**
I am used this code, to try and concatenate the dataframes together.
`pd.concat([restaurant_df, zipcodes_df['zipcode']])`
As my Dataframes have no identical columns, I thought this would work.

**Error I'm getting -**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-c7df07518b82> in <module>
----> 1 pd.concat([restaurant_df, zipcodes_df['zipcode']])

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    279         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    280         copy=copy,
--> 281         sort=sort,
    282     )
    283 

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    355                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid".format(typ=type(obj))
    356                 )
--> 357                 raise TypeError(msg)
    358 
    359             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'method'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

**Help:**
Expected outcome should be the one column from the `zipcodes_df` added to either the end (or ideally, after '`longitude`') of the `restaurants_df`.
Thank you in advance for all those who take the time to help!

Comment: What does type(restaurant_df) and type(zipcodes_df['zipcode']) print out just before pd.concat?

Comment: Per your comments below and the error above.  I suspect resturants_df isn't set correctly.  resturants_df isn't a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stick the column based on the index, you can do

```py
restaurant_df['zipcode'] = zipcodes_df.zipcode
```

To use different join options, look into the `how` parameter of the method below:

```py
restaurant_df.merge(zipcodes_df.zipcode, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get an AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'merge'

Comment: What are the types of `restaurant_df` and `zipcodes_df` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have learnt two lessons
1. Include ALL your code, to help members contribute effectively (I did not do this).
2. pd.read_csv() does not read a .csv into a DataFrame
**Solution:**
restaurant_df was initially read from a .csv file. I had never actually read the .csv as a DataFrame. I added this line of code and it works now :

```
restaurant_df = pd.read_csv('raw.csv')
```

AND...

```
restaurant_df = pd.DataFrame(restaurant_df)
```